# toFixed not working on Float32Array

Tags: javascript

Following code:

```
f = new Float32Array(1)
f[0] = 1.234567890
f[0] = f[0].toFixed(3)
console.log(f[0])
```

prints `1.2350000143051147` rather than `1.235`. Anyone know why?
If I change the `Float32Array` to a `Float64Array`, it works correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.toFixed()` function returns a **string**, not a number. When you assign that string back into the array, it's converted back to a number and the inherent inaccuracy becomes evident. The closest you can get to the decimal value 1.235 with a 32-bit binary floating point is (apparently) about 1.2350000143051147.

A *binary* floating point value cannot be "fixed", necessarily, to a set number of fractional *decimal* places.

Comment: Great, thanks!! (I should have thought of that myself...)

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge no problem. Note that the same thing applies to 64-bit values, but the added precision means that the code that turns the numbers into strings for printing rounds off the slight inaccuracy.